# What are my options (if any) for coding or scripting or at least designing my Apple watch face by myself?

Tags: apple-watch

I just got an Apple watch and selected a face that happens to have a small Earth showing my location and the daylight/nighttime distribution in my hemisphere.

This made me wonder if there are ways I can display other astronomical information, specifically what planets are currently in the sky and where they are roughly. Examples of this kind of information can be seen in in-the-sky.org's [planetarium mode](https://in-the-sky.org/skymap.php) for example, as well as many other planetarium programs and websites:

- [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982)

It is quite easy to generate a simple small database from which these positions *in the sky* can be calculated given lat/lon and date/time so if there are (easy) ways to script graphics on the watch's screen I might be able to attempt that manually, but I have no idea how accessible the screen is for such a project, and there may be easier ways of getting this.

**Question:** What are my options (if any) for coding or scripting or at least designing my Apple watch face by myself? For example, I'd like to see the positions of the Moon and planets *in the sky*. What are my options (if any) for coding it myself *if I can't find one that does what I want?*

**note:** There is an Astronomy watch face available, but if I understand correctly, it shows a crude flat 2D top-down map of the solar system only.

Answer (score 1):

Your options for coding Apple Watch faces (or parts of them) are really limited to only one option: Apple ClockKit.

You can find the documentation for it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit).

Using ClockKit you can build custom complications and timeline entries. It is also possible for you to customize a watch face with a mix of complications and save that to a `.watchface` file that you can bundle with your app to allow the user to quickly get the whole watch face setup per your design.